# Python: object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I did not understand the message sent by compiler. Can someone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/edboa_000/PycharmProjects/RESULTADOS_FINAIS 3/ggcc1/quadrante_aplicacao_forca9.py", line 13, in <module>
    matriz1[i-11][j] = posicao[j]
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

My code:

```
matriz1=((30,2))
for i in range(11,41):
    graof = np.genfromtxt('DMconf0%d.dat'%i,skip_header=10254, usecols=(0))
    grao = graof.astype('int')
    posicao = np.genfromtxt('DMconf0%d.dat'%i,skip_header=grao, usecols=(0,1), max_rows=1)
    for j in range(2):
         matriz1[i-11][j] = posicao[j] #line 13

print(matriz1)
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the traceback? It is quite clear.

Comment: This is not a matrix: `matriz1=((30,2))`. It's a tuple with two numbers.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `matriz1=((30,2))`?

Comment: guys, I saw where is my mistake. I should have written matriz1= np.zeros ((30.2)), in the first line. After making this correction the program ran. Thanks to everyone.